# Creating the equivalent Action<T1, T2> in Java from C#

Tags: java, action

I have code in C# that looks like:

```
 Action<Guid, QueryResult> onData = (guid, data) =>
 {
      total += data.NumberOfRows;
      Console.WriteLine("Guid: {0} Number of rows: {1}", guid, data.NumberOfRows);
 };
```

I would like to replicate this in Java, but Im unsure of the equivalent Java that would replace the Action code

Could anyone advise?

Comment: if you replace `=>` with `->`, this is already valid Java syntax. Captured variables must be final in a lambda, so `total` would need to become an AtomicInteger or something.

Comment: You could write your own functional interface `Action` in Java with two type arguments `T1` and `T2`, or use the existing `java.util.function.BiConsumer`.

Comment: This actually looks like a flaw in the underlying code and not the creation of an Action using BiConsumer, etc... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
 BiConsumer<String, Integer> resultBiConsumer = new BiConsumer<Guid, QueryResult>() {
     @Override
     public void accept(Guid s, QueryResult data) {
         total += data.numberOfRows;
         System.out.printf("Guid: %s  Number of rows: %d%n", s, data.numberOfRows);
     }
 };
```